# Meteor get client url in server method and subscription

Tags: meteor

Within, one of the `meteor method` and `meteor subscription`, 
need the ***complete client url***. How can i get this?

Note : Aready checked `this.connection.httpHeaders` but it gives the root url, i was looking for the full client url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the method and publication, why not adding the client URL as a parameter ?

```
Meteor.call(args, document.URL);
Meteor.subscribe(args, document.URL);
```

Comment: this option was there but the server side would make it clean and injection proof